# Custom time stamp for time series collected with Prometheus in java

Tags: java, utc, grafana, prometheus

I have a java application which uses the Prometheus library in order to collect metrics during execution.
Later I link the Prometheus server to Grafana in order to visualize those metrics. I was wondering if it is possible to make Grafana show a custom X axis for those metrics?
The usual X axis is in local time. Can I make it show data with timestamps in GPS / UTC time? Is it possible? If it is, what would it require? An additional metric parameter that holds the timestamps?

I declare the metric variable like this:

```
private static Counter someCounter = Counter.build()
            .name("someCounter_name").help("information counter").labelNames("SomeLable").register();
```

And add data like this:

```
someCounter.labels("test").inc();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? In the arguments where you can set the memory? You saying it from experiece or you are guessing?

Comment: Ok i will try. But why do you assume it will work? What exactly that line should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something to handle in Grafana. If you look at the dashboard (not panel) settings, under General there's a Timezone drop-down that allows you to select UTC rather than browser local time.

Comment: Thats right. Also i can manually add a time shift (leap seconds) if i want to make it GPS time.